# Which installer installs Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll?

Tags: .net, msbuild, installation

Our build scripts contain a task that uses `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll`, in the folder

```
$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\
```

(where `$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)` resolves to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild`)

On one developer machine the entire `Web` folder was missing.

Which installer installs `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll` and the related files in its folder?

Comment: I think it's if you install the Web Developer parts of VS. You should check what kink of projects that dev pc can build.

Comment: After I read the question title, the first thing that came to my mind was "Redmond", but I guess that doesn't pass as a valid answer...?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I was fearing that pun when I composed the question! Now reworded. :)

Comment: @RichardEv It's a shame you reworded the question :-D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer... `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll` gets added by the Visual Studio 2010 installer if you check the **Visual Web Developer** option.

Comment: I have VS2010 and VS2012 ultimate installed on my machine. I can't find that dll anywhere! When I installed both versions of VS, the only thing I skipped was SQL Server express editions because I have both SQL 2008 R2 and SQL 2012 (both are developer editions) installed side by side... Any idea on where to find it?

Comment: Ok never mind...$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32) is an MSBuild folder duh... I just found them

Comment: thanks, I had the same issue and also had to install the **Visual Web Developer** option to fix it.

Answer (score 7):

For **Visual Studio 2017**, you have to check **ASP.NET and web development tools** in **Individual components** tab.

Comment: That doesn't do it... there must be something else you checked too that includes it.

Comment: For me that inclusion did do it ... once I changed my project file from version 14.0 to 15.0.

Comment: @demongolem Why does the fact if the dll is installed would depend on the project file version? Can you elaborate on this. I see that both my solution file is already using Tools version 12.0, which means v15 (annotated in the solution file, not the project file). But why would this even matter? I need that dll and "ASP.NET and web development tools" is already installed.

Comment: Ok, I found the file, in case of VS 2017: c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll

Answer (score 2):

Maybe my answer will help somebody.
i'm using Jetbrains Rider and for one solution with SlowCheetah, i need to install VS to have 'Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll' dll.

My solution: copy folder '\tools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0' from some computer with installed VS and put it to the rider tools folder
'c:\Program Files\JetBrains\JetBrains Rider 2021.1.4\tools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0'

in my case everything is start working fine.

Comment: Thanks, what I did was to download `Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019`, then pointed the project to the installation folder and relevant DLLS

Comment: yes, this will work too. But i don't want to install any additional tools on my pc.

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2015, select this component in installer:
**Windows and Web Development\Microsoft Web Developer Tools**