# how to force config transform on an xml file?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

I've just installed [Configuration Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GolanAvraham.ConfigurationTransform) for VS2017, hoping to transform some XML files.

Unfortunately, it looks like it only does *.config files?!

For example, when I write click on a *.config file, I get the "add config transform" option, but it's not available for XML files:

[image]

**How do I transform an XML file?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unfortunately, it looks like it only does *.config files?!

Not true. You can transform any XML file. For example, in [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider), XML Transformation is used to build the `.nuspec` XML files for NuGet.

#### [MvcSiteMapProvider.Core.Shared.nuspec](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/0a63fe8a56b41e55b71c0d67ddf2988a9f69ee15/nuget/mvcsitemapprovider.core/MvcSiteMapProvider.Core.Shared.nuspec)

This is a "base" file that is later transformed.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- MvcSiteMapProvider.MVCx.Core shared Nuget specification file; all packages share this -->
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC#mvc_version#.Core</id>
        <title>MvcSiteMapProvider MVC#mvc_version# Core</title>
        <version>$version$</version>
        <authors>Maarten Balliauw, Shad Storhaug</authors>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <summary>MvcSiteMapProvider is a tool that provides flexible menus, breadcrumb trails, and SEO features for the ASP.NET MVC framework, similar to the ASP.NET SiteMapProvider model. The project is hosted on http://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider.</summary>
        <description>This package contains only the core library for MvcSiteMapProvider. Use this package if you need to reference the library from a non-MVC project such as a class library.</description>
        <language>en-US</language>
        <tags>mvc mvc#mvc_version# sitemap mvcsitemap menu breadcrumb navigation mvcsitemapprovider</tags>
        <projectUrl>http://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider</projectUrl>
        <iconUrl>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/master/map-icon.gif</iconUrl>
        <dependencies>
            <group targetFramework="net35">
            </group>
            <group targetFramework="net40">
            </group>
            <group targetFramework="net45">
            </group>
        </dependencies>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

#### [MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5.Core.nutrans](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/0a63fe8a56b41e55b71c0d67ddf2988a9f69ee15/nuget/mvcsitemapprovider.core/MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5.Core.nutrans)

Here is an XML transformation file that converts elements for MVC 5:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Nuget specification file for MVC5 -->
<package inherits="MvcSiteMapProvider.Shared.nuspec" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <metadata>
    <dependencies>
        <group targetFramework="net45" xdt:Locator="Match(targetFramework)">
            <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="[3,4)" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
            <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="[3,4)" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
            <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="[5,6)" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
        </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

#### Transformation

Here is an [MSBuild file named `TransformXml.proj`](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/0a63fe8a56b41e55b71c0d67ddf2988a9f69ee15/tools/TransformXml.proj) that is used to execute the XML transform:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Transform" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml"
        AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"/>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <Source></Source>
        <Transform></Transform>
        <Destination></Destination>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Transform">
        <TransformXml Source="$(Source)"
                  Transform="$(Transform)"
                  Destination="$(Destination)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

See [Which installer installs Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398092/which-installer-installs-microsoft-web-publishing-tasks-dll) for information about how to obtain `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll`.

And the [command to execute from PowerShell](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/build/runbuild.ps1#L112) looks like:

```
function Transform-Nuspec ([string] $source, [string] $transform, [string] $destination) {
    $transform_xml = "$tools_directory\TransformXml.proj"
    Write-Host "Creating nuspec for $destination" -ForegroundColor Green
    Exec { msbuild $transform_xml /p:Source=$source /p:Transform=$transform /p:Destination=$destination /v:minimal /nologo }
    $nuspec
}
```

The MSBuild command could be run from any type of script or process that can execute `MSBuild.exe`.